# Arc length of level sets

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $z = B \sin x \ \sin y+\cos x \ \cos y$. Where $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq y \leq \pi$. I need to find the length of the curve that describes a level set for any value of $B$.  That is, if I set $z = A$ (where $A$ is some scalar constant), what is the length of the level curve for any value of the parameter $B$.  Obviously some symmetry can be exploited to solve the problem, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to derive the length.

Comment: Are you sure the variables $x,y$ have not to satisfy some bound (e.g., $-\pi\leq x,y\leq \pi$)? For otherwise the problem is meaningless...

Answer (score 1):

The length is either 0 or infinity, depending on A and B, because the function z is periodic in x and in y.

Comment: Because the level sets are made of infinite closed curves (which can degenerate into points), I guess.

Comment: I should have specified, the domain is 0 <= x <= pi and 0 <= y <= pi.  The length is not always zero.  You can plot the level sets and geometrically determine the length for a few simple cases of A and B.  For example: when A = B = -1 the length (in the given domain) is pi*sqrt(2), when A = 0, and B = -1 the length is also pi*sqrt(2); however, when A = 0, and B -> 0 the length approaches 2*pi.  So in general the length is finite and nonzero, but there are a few special cases where the length will be zero.

Comment: @Pacciu

Comment: @okj: Then, why don't you edit your post and write "with $0\leq x,y\leq \pi$" somewhere in it? ;-)

Comment: @Pacciu: Thanks, I didn't realize I could edit the post, this is my first time on stackexchange.  I think the problem should be more easily understood now.